# RandomForest and tree feature importance in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

What is the difference between `model.feature_importances_` and `tree.feature_importances_` in the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

# Boston Housing dataset
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()
# Convert 'skleran.bunch' to Pandas dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)

# Create train and test sets for cross-validation
X,y = data.iloc[:,:-1], data.iloc[:,-1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state = 123)

model = RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

As I understand the following is importance of features:

```
importance = model.feature_importances_
importance_df = pd.DataFrame(importance, index=X_train.columns, 
                      columns=["Importance"])


        Importance
-----------------
CRIM    0.025993
ZN      0.002781
INDUS   0.004832
CHAS    0.000315
NOX     0.028655
RM      0.406285
AGE     0.017987
DIS     0.040696
RAD     0.003615
TAX     0.009281
PTRATIO 0.009103
B       0.012354
LSTAT   0.438106
```

And what is `tree.feature_importance`?:

```
[tree.feature_importances_ for tree in model.estimators_]
```

How do they differ, calculated and which is more important 0.2 or 0.9? Can't find in the docs.